# Trying to connect to ROS using rosserial-windows . Error with the IP address

Tags: c++, char, ip, ros, const-char

I am trying to connect to ROS using rosserial windows. I am following the tutorial given on the ROS website (http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_windows/Tutorials/Hello%20World)
here is what my code looks like:
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ros.h"
#include <std_msgs/Float32.h>
#include <windows.h>

using std::string;

int main(int argc, _TCHAR * argv[]){
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    char* ros_master = "172.17.194.162"; //error1
    printf("Connecting to server at %s\n", ros_master);
    nh.initNode(ros_master);//error2
    printf("Advertising message\n");
    std_msgs::Float32 a;
    ros::Publisher cmd("/truevision/throttle_cmd", &a);
    nh.advertise(cmd);
    printf("Go Car!\n");
    while (1){
        nh.spinOnce();
        Sleep(100);
    }
    printf("All done\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It is giving me errors

```
E0144 - const cahr cannot be used to initialize an entity of type char
C2664 - cannot convert argument 1 from const char to char
```

But this is exactly how it is done in the tutorial. can't seem to figure out what is wrong here.

Comment: Tutorial is wrong.

Comment: This code is terrible as a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems more like just plain C, and many conventions are wrong, but try changing `char* ros_master = "172.17.194.162";` to `std::string ros_master = "172.17.194.162";`

A better form of this code would use `std::cout` (as it is part of C++, not C) and wouldn't use `while (1)` (as `while(true)` would be more readable).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add "hostname: port" to the ros_master other than only the hostname. The default port for ros serial is 11411. Then your code should `ros_master="171.17.194.162:11411"` .